# Why are there two commands \> and \: that do the same thing?

Tags: math-mode, spacing, horizontal

The file `latex.ltx` says:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\:{\tmspace+\medmuskip{.2222em}}
\let\>=\:
```

Why are there two equally long commands `\>` and `\:` doing exactly the same thing? To me, they look redundant without reason. Wouldn't one command suffice?

(Just in case you argue that `\>` is already redefined in the `tabbing` environment: why not having given `\:` the go-to-the-next-column meaning in the tabbing environment and let `\>` retain its usual horizontal-spacing definition `\tmspace+\medmuskip{.2222em}`, which defaults to `\mskip+\medmuskip` in math mode, probably compatible with `\mskip\medmuskip` in plain TeX?)

Comment: There are many things decided by Lamport in LaTeX that are mysteries to someone who first learned plain TeX.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In plain TeX, Knuth used `\>` for `\mskip\medmuskip`:

```
\def\,{\mskip\thinmuskip}
\def\>{\mskip\medmuskip}
\def\;{\mskip\thickmuskip}
\def\!{\mskip-\thinmuskip}
```

LaTeX uses `\>` with a different meaning in `tabbing`. There would be little cause of conflicts, but since the beginning, Lamport decided to provide `\:` for doing `\mskip\medmuskip`, maybe also because he considered `,:;` a better mnemonic sequence, who knows?

In any case, for compatibility with plain TeX, which at the beginning was preferred because people could switch more easily, `\>` as an alias to `\:` was provided (only outside of `tabbing`, of course).

The definition of `\:` in the kernel was recently modified adopting the one in `amsmath` that allows to use it also in text mode, not only in math.

Comment: So Lamport might have thought `,:;` is mnemonic? Well, there is some sense to it.

Comment: Wouldn't the sequence ,;: be more logical?

Comment: @RaoulKessels But plain TeX already used `\;` for the thick space…